# webpack/babel-loader ReferenceError caused by relative pathing

Tags: webpack, babeljs, relay

I've been trying to set up this React + Relay example (https://github.com/RGRjs/rgrjs.com), and I'm having trouble with resolving the path to a webpack plugin for babel-loader. When I run webpack in my project directory, I get the ReferenceError problems, which I think is caused by webpack resolving plugin dependencies via the context of individual files it is trying to build.

Details:
I have my project structured as the linked repo:

```
rgrjs:
├── data
|   ├── schema.js
|   └── header.html
├── js
|   ├── app.js
|   └── components
|    |   └── Main.js
├── public
|   └── bundle.js
babelRelayPlugin.js
webpack.config.js
```

And with the webpack.config.js set up as below:

```
var projectRoot = process.env.PWD;
console.log('Project Rooted at ' + projectRoot);
module.exports = {
    context: projectRoot,
    entry: "./js/app.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/public",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        root: projectRoot
    },

    module:{
        loaders: [
            {
                test:/\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                babelrc: false,
                query: {
                    presets: ['react','es2015','stage-0'],
                    plugins: ['./babelRelayPlugin']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

When I try to build, I get the following error:

> ERROR in ./js/app.js
>   Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "./babelRelayPlugin" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to ".../rgrjs/js"

The referenced "babelRelayPlugin" is in the root "rgrjs" directory (which should be "./" relative to webpack. When I switch the plugin path definition to "../babelRelayPlugin", the ./js/app.js resolves the reference BUT I get a different problem:

> ERROR in ./js/components/Main.js
>   Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "../babelRelayPlugin" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to ".../rgrjs/js/components"

Other solutions seems to suggest using resolve/resolveLoader/context, but it hasn't seem to work for me as seen in the config file. Am I setting that up wrong or is this a genuine bug?

Best

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the issue here is that webpack is passing the plugin path as a string that is reevaluated within each transpile of a different file, and rather the path itself needs to be defined as a strict path, as below:

```
var projectRoot = process.env.PWD;
console.log('Project Rooted at ' + projectRoot);

var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    //...
    module:{
        loaders: [
            {
                //...
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react','es2015','stage-0'],
                    plugins: [path.resolve(projectRoot,'babelRelayPlugin')]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

This would appear to be inconsistently applied for different versions/builds, as the same config file and folder structure built fine on a different computer.